# What is the rationale behind the differences between the compiler diagnostics issued when it sees std::vector<Typo> and std::vector<struct Typo>

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Consider these two programs and their attempted compilations.

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<struct Typo> a; // Errors centered around `Typo` being an incomplete type
}
```

gcc 6.3, for example, gives error messages centered around `Typo` being an incomplete type, including

> /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_vector.h:161:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘`struct main()::Typo`’

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<Typo> b; // Errors centred around `Typo` not being defined
}
```

gcc 6.3, for example, gives errors centered around `Typo` not being defined, including

> prog.cpp:4:14: error: `‘Typo’` was not declared in this scope

Both vector instantiations are errors of course, but what is the rationale for the differing diagnostic messages as cited in the program comments?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @aschepler: Try this https://ideone.com/G1ASVz

Comment: That says it's using gcc 6.3. But I see almost the same error message twice. (I would expect something different if you had the second statement without the first statement.)

Comment: Because it's two different things? a) "You say there's a Typo, ok I get it, but it's incomplete". b) "There are no Typos around here, dude."

Comment: @jrok assume `Typo` is really a typo, ie there is a struct declared named `NoTypo`

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Am I a `std::numeric_limits<Typo>::max()`?

Comment: "On some compilers" doesn't make sense. Diagnostic messages depend ENTIRELY on the compiler. So you can ask a question about why gcc 6.3 has certain messages, but not why compilers in general have certain messages.

Comment: @user463035818 It doesn't matter, how is compiler supposed to know it's a typo?

Comment: @jrok compiler does not know, but it will issue two different diagnostics, that the point of the question

Comment: @user463035818: I'm not sure what that new class is for? Would you mind adding a comment?

Comment: @Bathsheba Rather `std::numeric_limits<Typo>::infinity()`.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, and my point is that it's correct to do so :)

Comment: @Bathsheba meh didnt really improve anything, rolled it back

Comment: @jrok then you could write an answer. Its obviously not that obvious to everybody ;)

Comment: Edited to be two programs, since it seems that's what you're actually asking about, and to specify gcc 6.3.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, it reads better now, thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`struct Typo` is an elaborated type specifier. That affects how name lookup works.

> **[basic.lookup.elab]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.elab#2): If the elaborated-type-specifier has no nested-name-specifier,
>   and unless the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with
>   the following form:
>
> ```
> class-key attribute-specifier-seq identifier ;
> ```
>
> the identifier is looked up according to [basic.lookup.unqual] but
>   ignoring any non-type names that have been declared. If the
>   elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by the enum keyword and this
>   lookup does not find a previously declared type-name, the
>   elaborated-type-specifier is ill-formed. If the
>   elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by the class-key and this
>   lookup does not find a previously declared type-name, or if the
>   elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> ```
> class-key attribute-specifier-seq identifier ;
> ```
>
> the elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the
>   class-name as described in [basic.scope.pdecl].

So in `std::vector<struct Typo> a;`, because `struct Typo` does not find a previously declared `Typo`, it serves as a forward declaration for the type. And as such, its the vector instantiation that *may*<sup>1</sup> complain the type it got is incomplete because it will try to do stuff with it.

While in `std::vector<Typo> b;`, looking up `Typo` finds nothing. There is no previous declaration for it, so its at this point a diagnostic should be issued that this identifier is undeclared.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Depends on what standard you are compiling to, and what members of the vector you are using. Support for incomplete types has been added.</sub>

Comment: *elaborate type specifier* - that's posh.

Comment: @Bathsheba - I'm not gonna complain :)

Comment: @Pi - Pardon me for quoting myself *"And as such, its the vector instantiation that may complain the type it got is incomplete"*.

Comment: So the forward decleration is not known at time when vector parsing would need it?

Comment: @Pi - No, I did not say that. The declaration *is known*. But the vector tries to use an incomplete type in a way that is not allowed (create objects of it, for instance).

Comment: Should it compile because with c++17 container incomplete type support http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4371.html?

Comment: @Oliv - Depends on what you do with the vector, though you definitely know that :) Added a footnote, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @StoryTeller still do not understand as Typo is complete before A is instantiated. https://godbolt.org/z/lVh3VK

Comment: @Pi - [It is not a complete type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#5). Our divide is around terminology it would seem.

Comment: @StoryTeller Our divide? I hardly have one, as I do not understand it ;)

Comment: @jrok DOHHH!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)  No more to add. Typo was well chosen. Thanks for pointing out :D

Comment: @Bathsheba FWIW, this is part of the reason you shouldn't use `struct` when talking about a `struct`.  If the declaration has not been seen then this acts as one which can have surprising effects.  I find you get better compiler errors (not declared in this scope) and in cases where incomplete types are allowed you won't even get a diagnostic at the typo point.